# Posting JSON array using Ajax and parse in servlet using Gson

Tags: java, ajax, parsing, servlets, gson

I am new to Java and stuck with this problem. I'm building an array in JavaScript which looks like this

```
  var jsonObj = [];

  jsonObj.push(
  {
     Effect: "Deny",
     RuleID: "Rule1"
   },
   {
     Effect: "Deny",
     RuleID: "Rule2"
   },
   {
     Effect: "Deny",
     RuleID: "Rule3"
    },....

    )
```

After this I am passing this to servlet using Ajax:

```
 jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: "http://localhost:8080/PolicyConsumerServlet/PolicyServlet",  
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {jsondata : JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},

     contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) { 

            alert('Hi');
        },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error occurred");
    } 
});
```

In servlet, in `doPost` method I have written below code

```
  StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
  String line = null;

  BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
  RequestMaker.requestProcess();
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      jb.append(line);

  String jsonstring = jb.toString(); 
  Gson gson = new Gson();

  Wrapper[] data = gson.fromJson(jsonstring, Wrapper[].class);

  System.out.println(jb);
```

and Wrapper class is

```
public class Wrapper {
  String Effect;
  String RuleID;
}
```

But this is throwing exception at below line

```
    Wrapper [] data = gson.fromJson(jsonstring, Wrapper[].class);
```

What is wrong in parsing this JSON?

Comment: Try adding a top level 'key' to the JSON you create in JavaScript. e.g. `{"data" : [..values]}`

Comment: But what is the issue with this approach?

Comment: Servlets is not my domain. But JSON, by definition needs to follow a key-value structure. Hence, the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, the string you are passing to the servlet is not a valid JSON.

You are passing an array of Wrapper, but in JSON an array is enclosed by square bracket. Moreover, due to generic erasure, you need to use a `TypeToken`.

I provide you with an example that shows the correct JSON for you case and how to parse it. It won't be difficult for you to copy and paste relevant part into your code. You can paste and run directly my example in you IDE to see it working.

```
package stackoverflow.questions;

import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import stackoverflow.questions.q18123430.Q18123430.ObjectA;

public class Test {

   public static class Wrapper {

      String Effect;
      String RuleID;

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Wrapper [Effect=" + Effect + ", RuleID=" + RuleID + "]";
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String json = "[ { \"Effect\": \"Deny\",  \"RuleID\": \"Rule1\" }, { \"Effect\": \"Deny\",  \"RuleID\":  \"Rule2\"  }]";
      Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Wrapper>>() {}.getType();

      Gson g = new Gson();
      List<Wrapper> list = g.fromJson(json, listType);
      for (Wrapper w : list)
         System.out.println(w);

   }
}
```

and this is the console result:

```
Wrapper [Effect=Deny, RuleID=Rule1]
Wrapper [Effect=Deny, RuleID=Rule2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe jQuery.ajax() API states that the data have to be converted into a query string using jQuery.param() and also content type have to be ***'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'***

The data argument data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string
in this case data is parameter of query string of url.

```
data =[
       {"Effect":"Deny","RuleID":"Rule1"},
       {"Effect":"Deny","RuleID":"Rule2"},{"Effect":"Deny","RuleID":"Rule3"}
      ]
```

In servlet you can get it from rquest paramater, not from reader.

```
String jsonData =  req.getParameter("jsondata");
```

If you will get data from inputStream or BufferedReader then you will get data in servlet as like below

```
jsondata=%5B%7B%22Effect%22%3A%22Deny%22%2C%22RuleID%22%3A%22Rule1%22%7D%2C%7B%22Effect%22%3A%22Deny%22%2C%22RuleID%22%3A%22Rule2%22%7D%2C%7B%22Effect%22%3A%22Deny%22%2C%22RuleID%22%3A%22Rule3%22%7D%5D
```

Here is firebug screen snap short[image: Fire bug console]

If you want to get data from reader object in servlet then you need to change ajax call optional data prameters as

```
data : JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
```

//Not this one

```
 data: {jsondata : JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},
```

Your ajax call is like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:8080/PolicyConsumerServlet/PolicyServlet",
          type : 'POST',
          dataType: "json",
          data : JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
           contentType : 'application/json',
           mimeType : 'application/json',
           success : function(data) {
                         alert('Hi');
                     },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error occurred");
                }
            });
```

datatype argument specifies the type of the data coming from server as json you need to set content type in servlet

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

You can send json response on stream as

```
response.getWriter().write(jsonString);
```